# Issue with snowflake returning text from api with a red dot

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does anyone know how I can remove this red dot from my data? It is causing issues, and not allowing me to replace text and cast to a date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what the `unicode` representation of that character is. You might have to use some string functions to locate that character if you don't have it handy. Once you have it, do

```
select unicode('the red dot character');
```

Then replace what that unicode represents as a character

```
select replace(col, char(that unicode number), '');
```

Sample implementation in case you have trouble locating the character

```
set str='r2_t1_date_c_2022_01_28';
select replace($str, char(unicode(split_part($str,'_',6))), ''); --unicode looks at the first character of a string/substring (in our case 6th underscore delimited part)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of characters repreented by "red dots" are non-printable:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CONCAT(seq8(), CHAR(seq8())), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seq8())
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR( ROWCOUNT => 1000 ));
```

[image]